# In VBA how do you return the name of an underlying query for a report object?

Tags: ms-access, vba, report

I would like to obtain the name of a query behind a specific report. I was hoping to do something like this...

```
 Dim QueryName As String
 QueryName = CurrentProject.AllReports(MyReportName).RecordSource.Name
```

However, I know this does not work, but I would like to find a means of doing this. Is there something I am obviously overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to open the report to get access to those kinds of properties.

Open in design mode so you don't actually run the thing.

```
Dim QueryName As String

DoCmd.OpenReport MyReportName, acViewDesign

QueryName = Reports(MyReportName).RecordSource

DoCmd.Close acReport, MyReportName
```