# MS Access How can I show the query name in a report

Tags: ms-access, report

If I make a report in MS Access then it is possible to let the program automatically fill in the name of the report, the actual time, the name of the report etc with the help of the code [name] Date() Time()

My question is if it is also possible that the program shows the query name (which is used for the report) on the report.

I have some reports on which I frequently change the query and it would be nice if the report automatically shows the name from the used query.

Comment: Duplicate of this question (which has a solution): http://stackoverflow.com/q/651558/20048

Answer (score 1):

This method worked for me with Access 2003.

I added an unbound text box, *txtRecordSource*, to the report footer.  Then used this for the footer's format event.

```
Private Sub ReportFooter_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.txtRecordSource = Me.RecordSource
End Sub
```

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding a textbox in my report with the code:  =[RecordSource]    and this worked fine.